# How to force the user to login to see any content using ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, simplemembership

I am working on a 'ASP.NET MVC 4' application and use 'SimpleMembershipProvider'. The application will be used in intranet and there will be no content available for not authorized users so I want to force login before letting the user to the actual site content.

I think this should be rather trivial task but it's the first time I have to implement such logic and I also want to do it `MVC 4/SimpleMemebrship` style so I seek advice.

The way I think it should be implemented is first to add this in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="15" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
```

after all I won't have action that will allow anonymous so I think it's better to put this here.

And changing my default Route to:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Which as I see it, will be the only action that will allow anonymous. However I'm a little bit concerned about changing the default route to `Login` I'm not sure if this won't lead to some unexpected drawbacks.

I also have the idea to keep the default structure created by the `MVC 4 Internet Template` and just leaving the `Index` action of the `Home` controller taking responsibility but I don't like this scenario because the logic is clear - the user must be logged in in order to gain any kind of access and even `Home/Index` is some access in my mind.

So what is the way to implement such kind of behavior? What are the basic steps, changes that I should make in order to implement this right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this by registering `Authorize` attribute as global filter. Bellow is an example of how your `RegisterGlobalFilters` method should look like:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

with this in place, you'll have to allow anonymous users to access the login page. To do that you annotate your Login action method with `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
 ...
}
```

Do the same for Login action method that receives POST request.